# emscripten blocking and resuming main()

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten, emcc

I am trying to basically imitate the `cin` functionality in a Wasm module taking the input of the user from an `.

I am approach the problem defining an `extern "C" function` which I will then import into my c++ code from JS using the `--js-library` flag.

I do manage to get the input of the user from an `<input>` but what I really cannot achieve is to let the c++ program to wait for the user to enter a value.

Another cue came to me from [this project](https://github.com/adam4321/Maze_Game_WASM). In [src/Main_Maze.cpp](https://github.com/adam4321/Maze_Game_WASM/blob/master/src/Maze_Main.cpp) the author achieves to get the input of the user and exiting the main function using:

```cpp
LOOP_SPEED = 60;
INF_LOOP = true;
void main(){
    /* CODE */
    emscripten_set_main_loop(start_prompt, LOOP_SPEED, INF_LOOP);
    ...
}
```

As far as I understood `start_prompt()` gets loaded into the main thread an it runs forever until  a user enters a value.

```cpp
void start_prompt(void) {

    int start_bool = 0;
    // Inline JS - Get the value entered into the faux CLI
    start_bool = EM_ASM_INT({
        return input;
    }, start_bool);

    // Select 1 to start
    if (start_bool == 1) {
        /* CODE */
        emscripten_cancel_main_loop();
        emscripten_set_main_loop(start_room, LOOP_SPEED, INF_LOOP);
    }
}
```

when the users inputs 1 the function calls `emscripten_cancel_main_loop()` and recall
`emscripten_set_main_loop(start_room, LOOP_SPEED, INF_LOOP)` to move into another function.

Now my question is:

How do I pause/exit the `main()` function, wait for the user input and RESUME the `main()`?

Looking at the emscripten documentation, I can see that there are many functions that block or pauses the execution of the main thread syncronously, like:

```
emscripten_push_uncounted_main_loop_blocker(...)
emscripten_pause_main_loop()
```

but nothing is working. Could you please point me to an example?
Please tell me if I should post my code.

Thank you